# Android: RelativeLayout in ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview, android-relativelayout

I have a `RelativeLayout` with multiple `ImageView`s and when I turn around the screen, the `ImageView`s become disordered. So I decided to wrap it into a `ScrollView`. But the `ScrollView` doesn't work!

Can any one help me with that? I know that the right way is to design a `GridView` or `ListView`, but since I had some questions and no one answered me, I decided to go this way.

Here is my *xml* code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="none" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/continuePizza"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="continue" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/finishP"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/continuePizza"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="finish" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/download" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:src="@drawable/download" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:src="@drawable/download" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/download" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView3"
        android:src="@drawable/download" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:src="@drawable/download" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/download" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView7"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView3"
        android:src="@drawable/download" />

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I experienced same problem with Relative Layout within Scroll View to overcome this i wrapped around my relative layout with a linear layout , try like this and also remove orientation from relative layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:scrollbars="none" >

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>


<Button
    android:id="@+id/continuePizza"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="continue" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/finishP"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/continuePizza"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="finish" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/download" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
    android:src="@drawable/download" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:src="@drawable/download" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/download" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView3"
    android:src="@drawable/download" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView5"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    android:src="@drawable/download" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView5"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/download" />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView7"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView3"
    android:src="@drawable/download" />

</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I deleted "android:fillViewport="true"" and it worked! tnx :)

Comment: if you face some other problem on deleting android:fillViewport="true" later on then try putting the scrollview inside the linear layout i.e Linear Layout --> scrollview --> relative layout

Answer (score 32):

Simple Solution, just add android:fillViewport="true" to Scrollview like :

```
<ScrollView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

<RelativeLayout ....... />

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use the ScrollView, you should know that you only can scroll when height of ScrollView smaller than height of ScrollView's child.
To solve this problem, you can define the Height of LinearLayout to match_parent, which is the only child of ScrollView. Then define the Height of ScrollView in the Java code, like `scrollView.getChildAt(0).getHeight() - 1;`  to make sure the height of ScrollView smaller than height of ScrollView's child.
For your own answer, it's not a good way to use magic numbers in your code, like 427dp and 548dp.

Answer (score -4):

I could solve my question with help of dear Ravi and a little bit change : 
the code goes like that :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="none" >



       <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="427dp" >



<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="548dp" >




    <Button
        android:id="@+id/continuePizza"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="continue" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/finishP"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/continuePizza"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="finish" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/download" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:src="@drawable/download" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:src="@drawable/download" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/download" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView3"
        android:src="@drawable/download" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:src="@drawable/download" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/download" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView7"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView3"
        android:src="@drawable/download" />

</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I don't think hardcoding the height dimensions is the way to go.