# Android - Relative layout inside ScrollView

Tags: android, scrollview, android-relativelayout

How can I put relative layout inside a scrollview? I want a scrollable view that contains pictures and texts like this:

[image: The screen should look like this]

I searched the Internet for solution or example, but in every sample project they use linear layout. Please help!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By looking on your mock I think you should use `ListView`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18677421/relative-layout-in-scrollview


and an older question

Comment: post your code and XML layout what you tried until now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look [at this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/) it has exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you are describing + your mock, you should use a [ListView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) with a header that contains your picture (on the top of the list)