# Multi child Relativelayout Scroll in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm to trying to create a user information form in my layout. I have multiple `RelativeLayout`. Its not scrolling down to fill other information. Please see my layout. It should scroll down to fill other `EditText` also.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/viewBg"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="zesteve.com.myapplication.AddNewBusiness">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:title="Add New Business" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/uname"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:paddingTop="8dp">

            <zesteve.com.myapplication.font.RobotoTextView
                android:id="@+id/personal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:paddingTop="3dp"
                android:text="Your Business Name *"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="12dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/personalname"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/personal"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/material_grey_300"
                android:hint="Your Full Name"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textColorHint="#ccc"
                android:textSize="15dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/bname"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/uname"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:background="@color/white">

            <zesteve.com.myapplication.font.RobotoTextView
                android:id="@+id/business"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:text="Your Business Name *"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="12dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/businessname"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/business"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/material_grey_300"
                android:hint="e.g. Pizza Hut"
                android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textColorHint="#ccc"
                android:textSize="15dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/locat"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/bname"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:background="@color/white">

            <zesteve.com.myapplication.font.RobotoTextView
                android:id="@+id/loc"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:text="Location *"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="12dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/location"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/loc"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/material_grey_300"
                android:hint="SELECT LOCATION"
                android:inputType="none"
                android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:paddingRight="15dp"
                android:paddingTop="15dp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textColorHint="#ccc"
                android:textSize="14dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/locicon"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/loc"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/rightangle" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/phone_no"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/locat"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:background="@color/white">

            <zesteve.com.myapplication.font.RobotoTextView
                android:id="@+id/phoneno"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:text="Phone Number *"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="12dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/contact"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/phoneno"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/material_grey_300"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textColorHint="#ccc"
                android:textSize="16dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/bcat"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/phone_no"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:background="@color/white">

            <zesteve.com.myapplication.font.RobotoTextView
                android:id="@+id/selectcat"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:text="Select Catagory *"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="12dp" />

            <zesteve.com.myapplication.MultiSelectionSpinner.MultiSelectionSpinner
                android:id="@+id/mySpinner"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/selectcat"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/material_grey_300"
                android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:popupBackground="#fff" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/bweb"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/bcat"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:background="@color/white">

            <zesteve.com.myapplication.font.RobotoTextView
                android:id="@+id/web"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:text="Your Website Name"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="12dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/website"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/web"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/material_grey_300"
                android:hint="e.g. www.zesteve.com"
                android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textColorHint="#ccc"
                android:textSize="15dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <zesteve.com.myapplication.font.RobotoTextView
            android:id="@+id/ower"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/bweb"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:text="ARE YOU THE OWNER/MANAGER"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/owners"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ower"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:background="@color/white">

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp">

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/notown"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:text="No, I am not the Manager" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/yesowner"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/notown"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:text="Yes, I am the Manager" />
            </RadioGroup>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/wcon"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/owners"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <zesteve.com.myapplication.font.RobotoTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:text="OWNER DETAILS"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:background="@color/white">

                <zesteve.com.myapplication.font.RobotoTextView
                    android:id="@+id/owncont"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:text="Your Phone Number"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="12dp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/ownerphone"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/owncont"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/material_grey_300"
                    android:hint="e.g. www.zesteve.com"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                    android:paddingTop="8dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textColorHint="#ccc"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <zesteve.com.myapplication.font.RobotoTextView
            android:id="@+id/disc"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/wcon"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:text="ADDITIONAL INFORMATION"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/ainfo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/disc"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:background="@color/white">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/addinfo"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="top|left"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:lines="6"
                android:maxLines="10"
                android:minLines="4"
                android:scrollbars="vertical" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I tried `ScrollView` but its giving this error -

> ScrollView can host only one direct child

Comment: add `android:fillViewport="true"` to Scrollview [Relative Layout in ScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18677421/relative-layout-in-scrollview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed some of the values in your layout. But anyway, here's your layout should look like.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:title="Add New Business" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/uname"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/colorWhite"
                android:paddingTop="8dp">

                <zesteve.com.myapplication.font.RobotoTextView
                    android:id="@+id/personal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                    android:paddingTop="3dp"
                    android:text="Your Business Name *"
                    android:textColor="@@color/md_divider_black"
                    android:textSize="12dp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/personalname"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/personal"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/material_grey_300"
                    android:hint="Your Full Name"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                    android:paddingTop="8dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/md_divider_black"
                    android:textColorHint="#ccc"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/bname"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/uname"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:background="@color/colorWhite">

                <zesteve.com.myapplication.font.RobotoTextView
                    android:id="@+id/business"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:text="Your Business Name *"
                    android:textColor="@@color/md_divider_black"
                    android:textSize="12dp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/businessname"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/business"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/material_grey_300"
                    android:hint="e.g. Pizza Hut"
                    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                    android:paddingTop="8dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/md_divider_black"
                    android:textColorHint="#ccc"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/locat"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/bname"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:background="@color/colorWhite">

                <zesteve.com.myapplication.font.RobotoTextView
                    android:id="@+id/loc"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:text="Location *"
                    android:textColor="@@color/md_divider_black"
                    android:textSize="12dp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/location"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/loc"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/material_grey_300"
                    android:hint="SELECT LOCATION"
                    android:inputType="none"
                    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                    android:paddingRight="15dp"
                    android:paddingTop="15dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/md_divider_black"
                    android:textColorHint="#ccc"
                    android:textSize="14dp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/locicon"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/loc"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_profile" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/phone_no"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/locat"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:background="@color/colorWhite">

                <zesteve.com.myapplication.font.RobotoTextView
                    android:id="@+id/phoneno"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:text="Phone Number *"
                    android:textColor="@@color/md_divider_black"
                    android:textSize="12dp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/contact"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/phoneno"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/material_grey_300"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                    android:paddingTop="8dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/md_divider_black"
                    android:textColorHint="#ccc"
                    android:textSize="16dp" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/bcat"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/phone_no"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:background="@color/colorWhite">

                <zesteve.com.myapplication.font.RobotoTextView
                    android:id="@+id/selectcat"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:text="Select Catagory *"
                    android:textColor="@@color/md_divider_black"
                    android:textSize="12dp" />

                <zesteve.com.myapplication.MultiSelectionSpinner.MultiSelectionSpinner
                    android:id="@+id/mySpinner"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/selectcat"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/material_grey_300"
                    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:popupBackground="#fff" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/bweb"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/bcat"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:background="@color/colorWhite">

                <zesteve.com.myapplication.font.RobotoTextView
                    android:id="@+id/web"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:text="Your Website Name"
                    android:textColor="@@color/md_divider_black"
                    android:textSize="12dp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/website"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/web"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/material_grey_300"
                    android:hint="e.g. www.zesteve.com"
                    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                    android:paddingTop="8dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/md_divider_black"
                    android:textColorHint="#ccc"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <zesteve.com.myapplication.font.RobotoTextView
                android:id="@+id/ower"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/bweb"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:text="ARE YOU THE OWNER/MANAGER"
                android:textColor="@@color/md_divider_black" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/owners"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/ower"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:background="@color/colorWhite">

                <RadioGroup
                    android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp">

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/notown"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:text="No, I am not the Manager" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/yesowner"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/notown"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:text="Yes, I am the Manager" />
                </RadioGroup>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/wcon"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/owners"
                android:visibility="gone">

                <zesteve.com.myapplication.font.RobotoTextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                    android:paddingTop="8dp"
                    android:text="OWNER DETAILS"
                    android:textColor="@@color/md_divider_black" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorWhite">

                    <zesteve.com.myapplication.font.RobotoTextView
                        android:id="@+id/owncont"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp"
                        android:text="Your Phone Number"
                        android:textColor="@@color/md_divider_black"
                        android:textSize="12dp" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/ownerphone"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/owncont"
                        android:backgroundTint="@color/material_grey_300"
                        android:hint="e.g. www.zesteve.com"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                        android:paddingTop="8dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/md_divider_black"
                        android:textColorHint="#ccc"
                        android:textSize="15dp" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <zesteve.com.myapplication.font.RobotoTextView
                android:id="@+id/disc"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/wcon"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:text="ADDITIONAL INFORMATION"
                android:textColor="@@color/md_divider_black" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/ainfo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/disc"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:background="@color/colorWhite">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/addinfo"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="top|left"
                    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                    android:lines="6"
                    android:maxLines="10"
                    android:minLines="4"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: its scrolling but inside scroll view android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar". toolbar not showing

Comment: Glad to know that helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

Put your top level RelativeLayout inside the ScrollView.  That way it only has 1 direct child.

Comment: Then you did it wrong. If you put the entire relative layout on it, and nothing else, it will work. Or you're altering it in coffee and adding new children there